# Can MSSQL run alongside MySQL?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, sql

I'm currently evaluating Expression Engine for our company but need to install MySQL onto a DB server that already has MSSQL2005 running on it. Should I expect any compatibility problems or any other issues from running both SQLs alongside each other?

Thanks in advance,
Brett

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be fine - The fact that they are both Database servers is irrelevant as they communicate on different ports.  MySQL normally runs on port 3306 & MSSQL Sever on ports 1433 and 1434.

You may perhaps have performance issues running both, but otherwise they should mind their own business.

For what it's worth, I'd recommend virtualizing MySQL rather than adding it to another server, especially if it is a production server - makes troubleshooting and removal so much easier!

Comment: I'd like to virtualise but we can't for another 12 months! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: depending on expected usage, you may want to limit the amount of RAM each database process will use to stop sqlserver/mysql having a fight to the death for resources if they're both running high volume